# EE Control Panel Loading Slow

Tags: control-panel

I have a problem about my control panel menu loading
it’s run slow, especially about anything run with js i think
the hover menu like menu Design, Members, etc are not showing up
then i try to enter template manager link after i view the source code
but it’s not working when i try to select template groups

i think the problem is the js, because after i view the source code, then i try to open every js in the page, but there is one link that slow to load

it’s located here: /admin.php?S=025e0f4f2e17084ef824276564d10053&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,sortable,dialog&plugin=ee_interact.event,ee_broadcast.event,ee_notice,ee_txtarea,tablesorter,ee_toggle_all,ee_navigation&file=json2,underscore,cp/global_start&v=1383269521

have anyone ever experienced problem like this? how to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Best Regards,
.mafaik

Comment: Is this on all the pages? Or just specific ones? Do you have Playa installed? Any other add-ons?